# Magento - show prices only for particular customer group

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

how can I show the prices in Magento for only a particular group of customers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get current customer's group id use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Customize `Mage_Catelog_Block_Price` and check there id of customer's group